# Handle situation when image cannot be rendered

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, exception

I have spring mvc application

Sometimes on our site we can see that in `html` exists `img` tag but actually `url` is broken.

Now we want show default image for all these situations.

How can we handle it in single place and we should hit at this place only when we want to load image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using jQuery. On the **document.ready** you can check the url of all images, and check if the images are valid. If not you can just change for your image.

Here is the jQuery code (you must add it on all your pages):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = $('img').each(function(i, image){
        checkSrc(image);
    });
});

function checkSrc(image){
    $.get($(image).attr('src'), function() {
    //succes, we do nothing
    }).fail(function() {
        $(image).attr('src','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Cristiano_Ajax.jpg/220px-Cristiano_Ajax.jpg');
    });
}
```

Here the html:

```
<img src="notexisting.jpg"/>
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bx5kkoun/

**WARINING**

I don't recommend to do this because you have to request twice the images.
You can achieve it as well using *Java Filter*, but you must check as well the url of all images from server, but it's the same situation.

Comment: You must use `Java Filter` on that case, and update the response from teh server searching for all img tags and checking from server if the url is valid -> I would not recommend that.

Comment: how can I understand in filter that this request was send for image ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="loadDefaultImage()">
```

This solution is cross-browser, but not [IE8 and below.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

You have many options for the loadDefaultImage function, you could use the jQuery method already suggested (just use the fail part), here is another [suggestion](http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2014/03/05/html-image-tags-and-onerror-javascript-handlers/), or just google "image tag onerror example" and select an option that works for you.

I think resolving it on the client side is the most efficient way to go. It will only attempt an extra request if there is a failure. If you attempt a solution on the server side, you would have to test for success/failure and then modify the markup sent to the browser. The browser will have to load even the successful images again as the page is rendering.

Here is a possible implementation:

```js
function loadDefaultImage(element) {
  $(element).attr(
    'src',
    'https://placehold.it/100x100'
  );  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px;margin-right:100px;display:inline-block;">
  <img src="image.gif">
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <img src="image.gif" onerror="loadDefaultImage(this)">
</div>
```